# Unable to create an upload keystore

Tags: java, android, flutter, google-play

I am using a windows machine. I added java path to the environment variables. I am following the flutter documentation to create an upload keystore. But I am unable to do it. Please suggest me what I am missing. Thanks.

Flutter documentation to create an upload keystore: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#create-an-upload-keystore

Command Prompt:

```
yashwanth@DESKTOP-2UKHSJ1 MINGW64 ~/ywork/app-developer-assignment (main)
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\yashwanth\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
bash: keytool: command not found

yashwanth@DESKTOP-2UKHSJ1 MINGW64 ~/ywork/app-developer-assignment (main)
$ cd app

yashwanth@DESKTOP-2UKHSJ1 MINGW64 ~/ywork/app-developer-assignment/app (main)
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\yashwanth\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
bash: keytool: command not found

$ C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java\keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\yashwanth\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
bash: C:Program: command not found

yashwanth@DESKTOP-2UKHSJ1 MINGW64 ~/ywork/app-developer-assignment/app (main)
$ C:\"Program Files"\Android\"Android Studio"\jre\bin\java\keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\yashwanth\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 
-validity 10000 -alias upload
bash: C:"Program: command not found
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to either add keytool to your path or access keytool directly.

Once you've added keytool to your path, you can retry the command.
Or
You can access keytool by navigating to the folder where your java is installed. keytool should be in the bin folder ie C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\keytool.exe

To run it from the folder, try
$ C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\dev\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload

Comment: I tried that too. But I am still unable to generate upload -keystore. @Joseph

Comment: Share the absolute path to your keytool.